# Program to remove proper nouns from paragraph

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a program that removes all the proper nouns from a paragraph that is parsed from Wikipedia.

```
no_pnoun_paragraph = ""
for i in range(len(clean_paragraph)):
  if clean_paragraph[i].isupper() == True and clean_paragraph[i - 2] != ".":
   cutoff = clean_paragraph[i:]
   delete = cutoff[:cutoff.find(" ")]
   clean_paragraph = clean_paragraph.replace(delete, "")
print clean_paragraph
```

This attempts to remove all the words that start with an uppercase letter but do not begin a sentence. I receive an error that the string index is out of range for the if statement.

How can I fix my code to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re` to do that:

```
clean_paragraph = 'You are right. We are Going to be there.'
no_pnoun_paragraph = re.sub(r'([^.])( [A-Z]\w*)', r'\1', clean_paragraph)
# 'You are right. We are to be there.'
```

Comment: Your code works great! Can you explain what is happening inside re.sub(). Thanks

Comment: @Ethan http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/regex/regular-expressions-in-python and https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/21/re.sub

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error is because of the following line of code

```
`clean_paragraph` = clean_paragraph.replace(delete, "")
```

since you are replacing it, the length of the clean_paragraph is reduced. But, when the for loop started `clean_paragraph` length was different.

For example:

Lets say, your clean_paragraph is `"Hello"`
when you do `len(clean_paragraph)` , length will be `5`
so, now..if you `replace 'l'`  as below

```
clean_paragraph = clean_paragraph.replace("l","")
```

then, length of the clean_paragraph is **reduced to 3**. 
But, since the for loop goes on, with a range of 0 to 5. but, since the previous operation reduced the size, when the index of for loop becomes 4, `clean_paragraph[4]` is *out of range* as currently, **clean_paragraph is "Heo"** and you are trying to access **4th index**